# Why can't I update the boolean value of my core data entity's attribute?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, attributes, boolean

This is really annoying me. In Objective-C, I have an `Item` entity with a boolean attribute `Deleted`. I would like to be able to set the value of `Deleted` to YES or 1.

This is my code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSString *itemID = [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:(int)[currentTable selectedRow]] valueForKey:@"ItemID"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ItemID = %@", itemID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
Item *objectToDelete = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
if (objectToDelete == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}

[fetchRequest release];

[objectToDelete setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"Deleted"];

[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Something to note is that I am able to successfully change different attributes; for example: I add the string -DEL to the end of the `Item`'s attributes `Code` and `Name`. When I view a table of data, the strings for those values are updated correspondingly, however the value for `Deleted` continues to be 0.

Comment: What does your Entity description look like?  Are you using native integral types?  What do you get when you call valueForKey:@"Deleted"

Comment: My Entity header file for Item has NSNumber * Deleted. In the core data model it is listed as Boolean. When I call valueForKey:@"Deleted" after having changed it, it prints out "0".

Comment: Does your attribute is declared as transient? Then, try to put a log statement before and after the update. Let me know.

Comment: Are you sure your property names begin with uppercase letter? Core Data naming convention does not allow that. Check it again.

Comment: My attribute is not described as transient, and the entity name is Item, and the attribute name is Deleted. What would the property name be?

Comment: I encountered exactly the same situation. Terrible design of NSManagedObject :-||

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would highly highly highly recommend using a different name for this attribute. `NSManagedObject` already has methods closely related to this name (in particular `-isDeleted`) which is potentially resulting in collisions with your custom attribute name. As [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPropertyDescription_Class/NSPropertyDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPropertyDescription) for `NSPropertyDescription` says:

> Note that a property name cannot be the same as any no-parameter
>   method name of NSObject or NSManagedObject. For example, you cannot
>   give a property the name "description". There are hundreds of methods
>   on NSObject which may conflict with property names—and this list can
>   grow without warning from frameworks or other libraries. You should
>   avoid very general words (like "font”, and “color”) and words or
>   phrases which overlap with Cocoa paradigms (such as “isEditing” and
>   “objectSpecifier”).

Does your code work if you change the name of your property to something not likely to collide with any other property/method names?

Comment: That's the trick. I changed the "Deleted" attribute to "DeletedBoolean". A couple reflections in the code and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much.

Comment: More than an hour I tried to figure out why I can't set "deleted" property to "1", thanks.